# How do I loop over the columns of a data import in an SSIS Script Component without needing the column names?

Tags: c#, loops, import, ssis

I'm trying to import an Excel file in SSIS that has merged cells, and SSIS reads those merged cells as NULL other than the first cell which has the data.

I'm trying to parse the information and for that I want to apply the merged cell data to every cell that was merged previously.

I have this code that I found that applies the code to the F1 column (In my Input)

```
    // This script adjusts the value of all string fields
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    string filledField1 = "";

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        // Check if the value is null
        if (Row.F1_IsNull)
        {
            // If null => replace value by variable
            Row.F1 = filledField1;
        }
        else
        {
            // If not null => replace variable by value
            filledField1 = Row.F1;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to apply this code for multiple columns through a foreach loop, but I can only do it if I know the names of the columns previously.

How can I transform this code to apply the transformation for every row of every column instead of the F1 column only?

PS: Old heading was "Apply row transformation for multiple input columns in Script Transformation", but this was changed since the question stands for the loop over columns as such.

Comment: This seems to be near [Looping Through Columns in SSIS Script Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960082/looping-through-columns-in-ssis-script-component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to genercize it. If someone knows otherwise, I'll be happy to delete this and bounty their answer.

The Why it can't be done is that in your `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method, in `ScriptMain` class, accepts an `Input0Buffer` as the parameter. Input0Buffer is an autogenerated class. The following comment heads the `BufferWrapper.cs` file which defines the Input0Buffer class

```
/* THIS IS AUTO-GENERATED CODE THAT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN! DO NOT EDIT!
*  Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services buffer wrappers
*  This module defines classes for accessing data flow buffers
*  THIS IS AUTO-GENERATED CODE THAT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN! DO NOT EDIT! */
```

So, that class is what defines the things available to you in your ProcessInputMethod. It generates a bunch of getters and/or setter methods plus an IsNull method for all the columns you select *before* you clicked the "Edit script" button.

Input0Buffer is derived from the ScriptBuffer class. ScriptBuffer has as its definition

```
namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline
{
    public class ScriptBuffer
    {
        protected PipelineBuffer Buffer;
        protected int[] BufferColumnIndexes;

        public ScriptBuffer(PipelineBuffer BufferToUse, int[] BufferColumnIndexesToUse, OutputNameMap OutputMap);

        protected object this[int ColumnIndex] { get; set; }

        protected void AddRow();
        protected void DirectRow(string outputName);
        protected bool EndOfRowset();
        protected bool IsNull(int ColumnIndex);
        protected bool NextRow();
        protected void SetEndOfRowset();
        protected void SetNull(int ColumnIndex);
    }
}
```

What's important to note that the `PipelineBuffer` instance called Buffer, is defined as protected in the ScriptBuffer class. It is not defined as anything in our autogenerated class so it's not accessible outside that class definition. That means when we're *using* the instance, as we do inside our ScriptMain, we can't touch the protected members as they behave as if private.

I'm sure you could implement an IEnumerable something interface so you could do what you're wanting to do on the Input0Buffer class but know that every time you open the script up, Visual Studio is going to regenerate the class and obliterate your edits.

As I type this, I am making a note to check up on how [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) as they might provide an approach...

Comment: So it's another case of SSIS needing to know the metadata beforehand. Thank you then. I'll have to customize the code for the number of columns I want to fix. Good thing is that it's at most 3-4 columns.

Comment: I read your very good insights into the problem of a protected attribute that "is inaccessible due to its protection level", as I found it in my code when trying to loop over the columns of the Row object. Yet, there seems to be a way to loop over unseen columns of the Row object, and as you ask for it in your answer, I give you the hint to have a look at the other answer. Perhaps you have not seen it, four years later, but without having tested it, it seems to loop over the Row columns without having to know their names.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, you actually *can* access the underlying object in a script and iterate over a buffer, without using the named columns. You need to inherit the buffer and use this inherited class in `public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, string InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)`. I usually use a class inherited from Input0Buffer ( the autogenrated one) so I can access *both* the named and the iterateable columns.You can get the indexes to the columns by using `Reflection`
e.g.:

```
using System.Reflection;
...    
#region Input0ByIndexBuffer
//inherit via BufferWrapper 
    public class Input0ByIndexBuffer : Input0Buffer
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> ColumnIndexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public Input0ByIndexBuffer(PipelineBuffer Buffer, int[] BufferColumnIndexes, OutputNameMap OutputMap) : base(Buffer, BufferColumnIndexes, OutputMap)
        {
            IList<string> propertyList = new List<string>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperties())
                if (!property.Name.EndsWith("_IsNull"))
                    propertyList.Add(property.Name.ToUpperInvariant());
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyList.Count; i++)
                ColumnIndexes[propertyList[i]] = i;
        }
        new public bool IsNull(int columnIndex)
        {
            return base.IsNull(columnIndex);
        }
        new public void SetNull(int columnIndex)
        {
            base.SetNull(columnIndex);
        }
        new public object this[int ColumnIndex]
        {
            get
            {
                return base[ColumnIndex];
                // return GetObject(ColumnIndex);
            }
            set
            {
                //SetObject(ColumnIndex, value, false);
                base[ColumnIndex] = value;
            }
        }
        public BufferColumn GetColumnInfo(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetColumnInfo(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        //expose the Buffer.Get methods using the columnindex, this enables iterations over index instead of columns names
        public object GetObject(int columnIndex)
        {
            BufferColumn columnInfo = GetColumnInfo(columnIndex);
            switch (columnInfo.DataType)
            {
                case DataType.DT_BOOL:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_BOOL:
                    return GetBoolean(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_I2:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_I2:
                    return GetInt16(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_I4:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_I4:
                    return GetInt32(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_R4:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_R4:
                    return GetSingle(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_R8:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_R8:
                    return GetDouble(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_CY:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_CY:
                case DataType.DT_DECIMAL:
                case DataType.DT_NUMERIC:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DECIMAL:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_NUMERIC:
                    return GetDecimal(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_I1:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_I1:
                    return GetSByte(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_UI1:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI1:
                    return GetByte(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_UI2:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI2:
                    return GetUInt16(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_UI4:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI4:
                    return GetUInt32(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_I8:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_I8:
                    return GetInt64(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_UI8:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI8:
                    return GetUInt64(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_DBDATE:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBDATE:
                    return GetDate(columnIndex);
                case DataType.DT_DATE:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DATE:
                case DataType.DT_FILETIME:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_FILETIME:
                case DataType.DT_DBTIME:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIME:
                case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMP:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMP:
                case DataType.DT_DBTIME2:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIME2:
                case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET:
                case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMP2:
                case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMP2:
                    return GetDateTime(columnIndex);
                default:
                    throw new Exception(columnInfo.DataType.ToString() + " not yet supported ");
            }
        }
        public void SetObject(int columnIndex, object value, bool failSilently = true)
        {
            BufferColumn columnInfo = GetColumnInfo(columnIndex);
            try
            {
                switch (columnInfo.DataType)
                {
                    case DataType.DT_BOOL:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_BOOL:
                        SetBoolean(columnIndex, (bool)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_I2:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_I2:
                        SetInt16(columnIndex, (short)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_I4:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_I4:
                        SetInt32(columnIndex, (int)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_R4:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_R4:
                        SetSingle(columnIndex, (float)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_R8:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_R8:
                        SetDouble(columnIndex, (double)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_CY:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_CY:
                    case DataType.DT_DECIMAL:
                    case DataType.DT_NUMERIC:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DECIMAL:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_NUMERIC:
                        SetDecimal(columnIndex, (decimal)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_I1:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_I1:
                        SetSByte(columnIndex, (sbyte)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_UI1:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI1:
                        SetByte(columnIndex, (byte)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_UI2:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI2:
                        SetUInt16(columnIndex, (ushort)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_UI4:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI4:
                        SetUInt32(columnIndex, (uint)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_I8:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_I8:
                        SetInt64(columnIndex, (long)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_UI8:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_UI8:
                        SetUInt64(columnIndex, (ulong)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_DBDATE:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBDATE:
                        SetDate(columnIndex, (DateTime)value);
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_DATE:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DATE:
                    case DataType.DT_FILETIME:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_FILETIME:
                    case DataType.DT_DBTIME:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIME:
                    case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMP:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMP:
                    case DataType.DT_DBTIME2:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIME2:
                    case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET:
                    case DataType.DT_DBTIMESTAMP2:
                    case DataType.DT_BYREF_DBTIMESTAMP2:
                        SetDateTime(columnIndex, (DateTime)value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception(columnInfo.DataType.ToString() + " not yet supported ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (failSilently == false)
                    throw e;
                else
                    try { SetNull(columnIndex); } catch { }
            }
        }
        public sbyte GetSByte(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetSByte(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public byte GetByte(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetByte(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public bool GetBoolean(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetBoolean(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public short GetInt16(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetInt16(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public ushort GetUInt16(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetUInt16(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public int GetInt32(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public uint GetUInt32(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetUInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public long GetInt64(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetInt64(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public ulong GetUInt64(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetUInt64(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public decimal GetDecimal(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetDecimal(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public float GetSingle(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetSingle(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public double GetDouble(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetDouble(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public DateTime GetDateTime(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetDateTime(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public DateTime GetDate(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetDate(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public byte[] GetBytes(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetBytes(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetDateTimeOffset(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public Guid GetGuid(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetGuid(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public string GetString(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetString(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public TimeSpan GetTime(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetTime(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }

        //to test against componentwrapper?
        public uint GetBlobLength(int columnIndex)
        {
            return Buffer.GetBlobLength(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex]);
        }
        public byte[] GetBlobData(int columnIndex, int offset, int count)
        {
            return Buffer.GetBlobData(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], offset, count);
        }



        public void AddBlobData(int columnIndex, byte[] data)
        {
            Buffer.AddBlobData(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], data);
        }
        public void AddBlobData(int columnIndex, byte[] data, int count)
        {
            Buffer.AddBlobData(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], data, count);
        }
        public void ResetBlobData(int columnIndex)
        {
            Buffer.ResetBlobData(columnIndex);
        }
        public void SetBoolean(int columnIndex, bool value)
        {
            Buffer.SetBoolean(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetByte(int columnIndex, byte value)
        {
            Buffer.SetByte(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetBytes(int columnIndex, byte[] bytesValue)
        {
            Buffer.SetBytes(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], bytesValue);
        }
        public void SetDate(int columnIndex, DateTime value)
        {
            Buffer.SetDate(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetDateTime(int columnIndex, DateTime value)
        {
            Buffer.SetDateTime(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetDateTimeOffset(int columnIndex, DateTimeOffset value)
        {
            Buffer.SetDateTimeOffset(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetDecimal(int columnIndex, decimal value)
        {
            Buffer.SetDecimal(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetDouble(int columnIndex, double value)
        {
            Buffer.SetDouble(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetGuid(int columnIndex, Guid value)
        {
            Buffer.SetGuid(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetInt16(int columnIndex, short value)
        {
            Buffer.SetInt16(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetInt32(int columnIndex, int value)
        {
            Buffer.SetInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetInt64(int columnIndex, long value)
        {
            Buffer.SetInt64(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetSByte(int columnIndex, sbyte value)
        {
            Buffer.SetSByte(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetSingle(int columnIndex, float value)
        {
            Buffer.SetSingle(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetString(int columnIndex, string value)
        {
            Buffer.SetString(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetTime(int columnIndex, TimeSpan value)
        {
            Buffer.SetTime(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetUInt16(int columnIndex, ushort value)
        {
            Buffer.SetUInt16(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetUInt32(int columnIndex, uint value)
        {
            Buffer.SetUInt32(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
        public void SetUInt64(int columnIndex, ulong value)
        {
            Buffer.SetUInt64(BufferColumnIndexes[columnIndex], value);
        }
    }
#endregion
```

and use it in:

```
public void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0ByIndexBuffer Row)
{
    //do your code
}
public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, string InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
{
    if (InputName.Equals(@"Input 0", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Input0_ProcessInput(new Input0ByIndexBuffer(Buffer, GetColumnIndexes(InputID), OutputMap));
    }

}

public  void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0ByIndexBuffer Buffer)
{
    while (Buffer.NextRow())
    {
        Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
    }
}
```

The actual indexes to the column names I'll get from the Dictionary `ColumnIndexes`.

*(And the Dictionary gets its column names from `typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperties()`)*

Works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have wrapped up this answer here at [Looping Through Columns in SSIS Script Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960082/looping-through-columns-in-ssis-script-component).

Answer (score 0):

#### Two ways to loop

Whatever you do, in order to match the columns of the data source with the columns of the Row object after the import you need to match:

- their two indexes (data source index against Row object index)
- or their two modified (=Row object) names since the Row object only has modified column names where the space, underscores and minus signs are dropped. For example, the column name of the `Row` object of "my column_1-new" is "mycolumn1new". The name changes, and if you want to map the name against the original data source name, you need to shorten the name on both sides. I guess that SSIS needs to shorten the column names for the Row object to easily handle the names, mainly for the "_isNull" suffix that is put at the end as a new column for each original column which is a boolean column saying whether the value is null.

Thus, you can loop over the data source in two ways as follows.

##### Loop over the original column names of the data source

```cs
foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn in this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
    // Get the original column name
    string originalColumnName = inputColumn.Name;
    string modifiedColumnName = originalColumnName.Replace("_", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
```

##### Loop over the modified column names of the Row object

Or you loop over the Row object with:

```cs
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperties())
    // Get the modified column name
    string modifiedColumnName = property.Name;
```

As was done in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571665/11154841), but then you have lost the originalColumnName. If you need to match against a DataTable with the original column names, you will need to follow the other answer so that you know the index of each column while you loop over it by means of the Dictionary `` that the other answer has in the code:

```cs
        IList<string> propertyList = new List<string>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Input0Buffer).GetProperties())
            if (!property.Name.EndsWith("_IsNull"))
                propertyList.Add(property.Name.ToUpperInvariant());
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyList.Count; i++)
            ColumnIndexes[propertyList[i]] = i;
```

Check the full answer there for more, and I also wrapped it up and checked it at [Looping Through Columns in SSIS Script Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78228615/11154841).